# How to delete all the memory of BST that reuses pointers without having memory leaks?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, destructor

I am attempting to delete all the memory from a threaded BST. Basically, a clear() function for a BST. The way the BST is threaded is by reusing the right pointers as follows: if that pointer is nullptr, we re-use it as a way point to the next inorder key.

I know how to delete the memory from a normal BST, which goes like this:

```
void freeTree(NODE* node)
{
    if (node == nullptr) return;
    freeTree(node->left);
    freeTree(node->right);
    delete node;
}
```

When I run a valgrind report on the code above, I have no memory leaks. However, I have a segmentation fault.

So I changed it up, and reused this recursion for the right side. I get no seg fault when I use this, however my valgrind reports says I lose memory.

```
//helper function for below. I used it to help me traverse the right side of the BST for 
//printing purposes, so I assumed I can use this traversal for clearing.
NODE *rightNodeTraversal(NODE *node)
    {
        if (node->isThreaded)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            return node->right;
        }
    }

void freeTree(NODE* node)
    {
        if (node == nullptr) return;
        freeTree(node->left);
        freeTree(rightNodeDeletion(node));
        delete node;
    }
```

Here is how I use it my clear() function.

```
void clear()
{
    // DONE: write this function.
    if (root!= nullptr)
    {
        freeTree(root);
        root = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, here is the class I'm using and the insert() function.

```
template<typename keyType, typename valueType>
class mymap {
private:
    struct NODE {
        keyType key;  // used to build BST
        valueType value;  // stored data for the map
        NODE* left;  // links to left child
        NODE* right;  // links to right child
        int nL;  // number of nodes in left subtree
        int nR;  // number of nodes in right subtree
        bool isThreaded;
    };
    NODE* root;  // pointer to root node of the BST
    int size;  // # of key/value pairs in the mymap
    NODE *rightNodeTraversal(NODE *node)
    {
        if (node->isThreaded)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            return node->right;
        }
    }
    void _inOrderTraversalPrinting(NODE *root, ostream &output)
    {
        if (root == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }
        _inOrderTraversalPrinting(root->left, output);
        output << "key: " << root->key << " value: " << root->value << endl;
        _inOrderTraversalPrinting(rightNodeTraversal(root), output);
    }
    NODE *minKey(NODE *node)
    {
        NODE *curr = node;
        while (curr->left != nullptr)
        {
            curr = curr->left;
        }
        return curr;
    }
    void freeTree(NODE* node)
    {
        if (node == nullptr) return;
        freeTree(node->left);
        freeTree(rightNodeTraversal(node));
        delete node;
    }

    mymap()
    {
        // DONE: write this function.
        root = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
    void put(keyType key, valueType value)
    {
        // DONE: write this function.
        NODE *prev = nullptr;
        NODE *cur = root;
        while (cur != nullptr)
        {
            if (key == cur->key)
            {
                cur->value = value;
                return;
            }
            else if (key < cur->key)
            {
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur->left;
            }
            else
            {
                if (cur->isThreaded)
                {
                    prev = cur;
                    cur = nullptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev = cur;
                    cur = cur->right;
                }
            }
        }
        NODE *node = new NODE();
        node->key = key;
        node->value = value;
        node->right = nullptr;
        node->left = nullptr;
        if (prev == nullptr)
        {
            root = node;
            node->right = nullptr;
            node->left = nullptr;
        }
        else if(key < prev->key)
        {
            prev->left = node;
            node->right = prev;
            node->isThreaded = true;
        }
        else if(key > prev->key)
        {
            node->right = prev->right;
            node->isThreaded = true;
            prev->isThreaded = false;
            prev->right = node;
        }
        size++;
    }
};
```

Here is a starting code to test:

```
#include "mymap.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mymap <int, string> map;
    mymap <string, int> map2;
    mymap <int,int> map3;
    mymap <double, int> map4;
    mymap <char, int> map5;
    int arr[] = {2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6};
    int arr2[] = {2,1,3};
    int arrAns[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int arrAns2[] = {1,2,3};
    string arrStr[] = {"Do you", "remember me..", "We used", "to", "be in", "love"};
    string arrStrAns[] = {"be in", "Do you", "love", "to", "remember me", "We used"};
    double arrDouble[] = {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, .50, 2.33, 5.33};
    double arrDoubleAns[] = {.5, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.33, 5.33};
    char arrChar[] = {'a', 'a', 'd', 'v', 'b', 'z'};
    char arrCharAns[] = {'a', 'b', 'd', 'v', 'z'};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        map.put(arr[i], arrStr[i]);
        map2.put(arrStr[i], arr[i]);
        map4.put(arrDouble[i], arr[i]);
        map5.put(arrChar[i], arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        map3.put(arr[i], arr2[i]);
    }
    map.clear();
```

As said above, I tried my helper function. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: A word of advice: don't use the term "thread" for this. Use anything else. Something like "next" would be fine. Anyone who sees words like "thread" and "threaded" in code is gonna assume it's related to parallel processing, which in this case couldn't be further from reality.

Comment: My bad, I'm still learning. My professor calls it threads. I'll change it.

Comment: Your professor is living in a bubble. Regarding your actual issue, you first should be verifying your tree's integrity to make absolutely sure that traversing these "threads" does not skip over any nodes that you would normally visit through ordinary depth-first traversal. Also, try defining a constructor and destructor for `NODE` that outputs a message along with the node's pointer value and key. You could even update a static counter here to maintain how many allocated NODE values there are. It should be zero at the end. Run your program and investigate its behavior.

Comment: You don't have `mymap` destructor (which should call `clear()`) (copy/move constructor should be provided too (at least as deleted)). [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f5cf108b896fe61)

Comment: I share the concerns about the quality of the professor. `void freeTree(NODE* node)` points to a typical C approach (no classes). In this case, it happens to be a member of `mymap`, for no good reason. Yet the code uses `delete`, which is a low-level C++ operation. In idiomatic C++, we'd just use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` and we would not have _any_ of this complexity. The compiler will generate _all_ the necessary code.